# Recursively replace string using a CTE

Tags: sql-server, recursion, common-table-expression

I am having `lookup_table` as following:-

```
|  id  | Val |
+------+-----+
|    1 | A   |
|   11 | B   |
|  111 | C   |
| 1111 | D   |
```

I am creating words using the values from `lookup_table` like `$id!` and saving it into another table.
example : bad - $11!$1!$1111!

So my `data_table` will be something like,

```
|   expression    |
+-----------------+
| $111!$1!$11!    |         -- cab
| $1111!$1!$1111! |         -- dad
| $11!$1!$1111!  |          -- bad
```

I want to reverse-build the word from the data_table.

**What I've tried**: used `CHARINDEX` on `$` and `!` to get the first id from expression and tried to replace it with matching `val` from look_up table recursively using CTE. I was not getting the exact result I was getting, but with some filetring, I got something close.

**The query I've tried** :

```
;WITH cte AS
  (SELECT  replace(expression,'$' + CONVERT(varchar(10),id) + '!' ,val) AS 'expression',
        cnt =1
   FROM data_table
   JOIN lookup_table ON id = 
        SUBSTRING(
            SUBSTRING(expression, CHARINDEX('$', expression) + 1, LEN(expression) - CHARINDEX('$', expression)), 1, CHARINDEX('!', expression) - 2) 
    UNION ALL 
    SELECT replace(expression,'$' + CONVERT(varchar(10),id) + '!' ,val) AS 'expression' ,
                 cnt = cnt +1
    FROM cte
    JOIN lookup_table ON id = 
        SUBSTRING(
            SUBSTRING(expression, CHARINDEX('$', expression) + 1, LEN(expression) - CHARINDEX('$', expression)), 1, CHARINDEX('!', expression) - (cnt +2))
    WHERE CHARINDEX('$', expression) > 0 )
SELECT expression
FROM cte
WHERE CHARINDEX('$', expression) = 0
```

**Current output :**

```
| expression |
+------------+
| DAD        |
| CAB        |
```

**Expected output:**

```
| expression |
+------------+
| DAD        |
| CAB        |
| BAD        |
```

**[fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/35dec/2/0)**

What am I doing wrong?

**Edit:** There was a typo in the data setup in fiddler. `d` in bad was having five 1s instead of four. Thanks, DarkRob for pointing it out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try this. Instead of using recursive cte you may use multiple cte to create your expression. Since sql already introduced this `string_split` function to convert your row cell into rows on particular delimeter, this will make our work lot easier.

First we convert each cell value into individual rows. Further we can easily get our expression word by using inner join with lookup table. At the last using stuff we'll again get our string as we need.

```
;WITH CTE AS (
    SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY EXPRESSION) AS SLNO, * FROM data_table 
),
CT AS (
    SELECT *, REPLACE(VALUE,'$','') AS NEWVAL 
    FROM CTE CROSS APPLY string_split(EXPRESSION,'!')   WHERE VALUE <> ''
),
CTFINAL AS (
    SELECT * FROM CT INNER JOIN lookup_table AS LT ON CT.NEWVAL=LT.id
)
--SELECT * FROM CTFINAL
SELECT DISTINCT SLNO, 
    STUFF( (SELECT '' + VAL + '' FROM CTFINAL AS CFF WHERE CFF.SLNO=CF.SLNO FOR XML PATH('')), 1,0,'') AS MYVAL 
    FROM CTFINAL AS CF
```

Comment: Thanks, it is a way better approach. I will give it a try.
But still `bad` is coming as `ba` only in the output.

Comment: actually in your fiddle you write five 1 for d in word 'bad'. I think it is typos see `$11!$1!$11111!` here you have five 1 instead of 4. In your lookup_table there is nothing defined for five 1.

Comment: thanks for the spot. It seems my query was working all fine.

Comment: Accept the suggested edit to make your question correct, so that if someone taking reference for same then not get confused. You may also upvote it... ;)